# How can you know when all the asyncs requests you have called are done?

Tags: node.js

I use request to make http get requests and get the html of some pages.

The code I am using has this structure.

```
function updateAll()
{
    request(mainurl, function(error, response, html){
        //get urls from html
        Array.from(urls).forEach(function(url) {
            update1(url);
        });
    });
}

function update1(url)
{
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        //get urls from html
        Array.from(urls).forEach(function(url) {
            update2(url);
        });
    });
}

function update2(url)
{
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
        //get urls from html
        Array.from(urls).forEach(function(url) {
            results.push(url);
        });
    });
}
```

How can I know when it finishes updating?
Thank you.

Comment: You should consider using `Promise`s

Comment: Callbacks, Promises, Observables (event emitters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here is to use Promises API. But in case of raw decision needed: you can add callback parameters to all of your functions, and wait for the last of them are fired.